# How to compare (sub)nets?

Tags: algorithm, neo4j

For the sake of the question let's say there is a net of a few thousands cities and a million of travelers related to the cities that they've visited. On average every traveler has visited 50 cities however there are extremes of up to 1000.

1) The firs (simple) question is how to find for a given traveler a list of most similar travelers based on the similarity between the visited cities? I.e. we have 3 travelers which visited these citiers:

A: Seattle(WA), Baltimore(MD), Dallas(TX)
B: Portland(OR), DC, Austin(TX)
C: Seattle(WA), Portland(OR), DC, Baltimore(MD)

if we compare now the visited cities then for traveler A the most similar will be traveler C.

Since for every traveler the subnet of attended cities is essentially a list of directly connected nodes the comparison is relatively easy even without Cypher (not sure if there is an elegant way to do it via Cypher).

2) A more complex comparison scenario is not via the direct cities but their characteristics (states, countries, climate, population, attraction types, etc.) In our example every city is linked to a state which is linked to a territory. If we look for A's most similar traveler based on the territory then traveler B is the winner (although on the city level there are zero matches).

What are your thoughts on both questions?

Answer (score 0):

Well,
I think you would write your own algorithm in Java or any other JVM language against hte neo4j Java API, and expose it to the world e.g. using a neo4j server plugin, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-plugins.html

There are a lot of resources to get you started on writing these algos, you can look at the implementation of the neo4j graph algos, see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/master/community/graph-algo

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a graph approach to this problem, I would recommend to have the properties of the cities as nodes, and link the cities to the nodes.

Therefore, you would have something along these lines :

```
(user)-[:visited]->(city)-[:has_property]->(property #i)
```

You could easily find similar cities by the number of links they have to the same properties.

You query would simply amount to a basic recommendation that can be implemented with cypher, with something along these lines (not tested, but you should get the idea) :

```
start A=node:users("")
match A-[:visited]->()-[:has_properties]->p
with distinct p as p
match p<-[r:has_properties]-cities
with distinct cities, count(r) as sim_score
order by sim_score desc limit 10
match cities<-[r:visited]-similar
return count(r) as score, similar
order by score desc limit 5
```

It works in 3 steps:

- get the properties of the cities visited by user A (the "feature extraction" part)
- then from the features, get the most similar cities
- and finally retrieve the similar users who have the same "profile"

For performance issue, you can calculate the cities similarities offline, because it is something that shouldn't change very often, and focus on the "real-time" only for users similarity, which is  less predictable.

Also don't forget to put enough RAM to your server ;)